# How to include latest posts short code inside contact form 7 email in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, html-email, shortcode, contact-form-7

I am currently using  [contact form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin for forms within my blog.

In a form when customers put messages, it sends a thank you message also for customer. In that mail, I need to include latest posts from my blog. I use a short code for that. Short code is working fine when adding it into a page. But it is not working in that email. It Just showing the short code.

Following is the short code. Please guide me If there is any configurations to do before using short codes inside contact form 7 emails.

```
[mk_blog style="thumbnail" pagination_style="2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, the only way I can think of doing this without creating an addon for CF7 would be to update the email that is sent with the latest links to your blog

Answer (score 0):

You can try to filter the email template with the filter `wpcf7_mail_components`. [Look here the source code](https://github.com/wp-plugins/contact-form-7/blob/master/includes/mail.php#L61)

And then with `do_shortcode();` execute the body shortcode.

I didn't try that, but its my first idea.

Edit: like this:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_mail_components', function($components) {
    $components['body'] = do_shortcode($components['body']);

    return $components;
});
```